# Forms for lists generated by SPSource aren't showing some masterpage elements

Tags: spsource

We used SPSource to create the schema.xml and the list files.  When I then navigate to the list, it doesn't show some of the custom master page elements.

Here is a screen shot where its not showing the quicklaunch navigation control.
[image]
http://i134.photobucket.com/albums/q113/walshieau/Image-2.png

Answer (score 1):

Mate can you add this to the SPSource Issues so it's targetted, the only reason I caught this was because of the @SPOverFlow tweet ;-)

What version are you using? I release v1.1.0.0 on Saturday.
http://spsource.codeplex.com/Thread/List.aspx

If it is an issue I can then raise this as an issue in TFS on CodePlex ;-)